# How to click on Web check box using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I check the table checkbox?

I tried clicking.

```
ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("x-grid3-hd-checker").Checked = True
```

```html
<div class="x-grid3-hd-inner x-grid3-hd-checker x-grid3-hd-checker-on" unselectable="on" style="">
    <a class="x-grid3-hd-btn" href="#"></a>
    <div class="x-grid3-hd-checker">&nbsp;</div>
    <img class="x-grid3-sort-icon" src="/javascript/extjs/resources/images/default/s.gif">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a checkbox in the HTML code. But you use getElementsByClassName() in a wrong way for your case. getElement**s**ByClassName() generates a node collection. If you need a specific node, you must get it by it's index in the node collection. First element has index 0.

Please note that the div tag with the CSS class *class="x-grid3-hd-inner x-grid3-hd-checker x-grid3-hd-checker-on "* is also included in the Node Collection, because a part of the class identifier is identical to *"x-grid3-hd-checker "*. [Edit: I'm not realy sure if the part must maybe stand at the begin of the identifier]

If you want to check this:

```
<div class="x-grid3-hd-checker">&nbsp;</div>
```

Your code needs the second index of the node collection:

```
ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("x-grid3-hd-checker")(1).Checked = True
```

But if there are more tags with the class name *"x-grid3-hd-checker"* the above line don't work. I can't say anymore until you don't post more HTML and VBA code. The best would be a link to the site.